# Granular updates of arrays with PATCH.

Tags: json, rest

I grab a resource from a target server using REST and get back this:

```
{
  "a" : [1,2], 
  "b": 1
}
```

I understand it's better to use `PATCH` instead of `PUT`ing the whole thing back when I want to update, to avoid overwriting any changes made to that resource in the time I have pulled it and the time I'm pushing it back.

Having just read [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#page-3) to understand how to use PATCH properly, I try to use it to fine-grain my update to an array. I want to update the second array element to the value 1.

```
REQUEST:
[
  {"op" : "add", "path": "/a/1", "value" : 1 }
]
RESULT:
  {
    "a": [1,1,2]
    "b": 1
  }
```

Ah! I don't use add, I use replace, because add causes an insert. So I'll change that:

```
REQUEST:
[
  {"op" : "replace", "path": "/a/1", "value" : 1 }
]
```

And now it could error. Because in the time since I pulled the resource and I'm pushing it back, any number of changes could've been made to the array `a`. In particular, the second array element which currently contains `2` could've been removed completely. `replace` attempts to replacing an existing element, if that second array element isn't there it will error - in that case, `add` would've been the solution.

I don't see how fine-grained adjustments to arrays is possible. At this point the only way I could see doing this error free is the following:

```
[
  {"op" : "replace", "path" : "/a", "value": [1,1]}
]
```

It might be error-free but it's bad, because I re-sent the value for the first array element, which could've been modified in that time.

Arrays won't contain just primitive values, they can contain any nested structure of objects. It seems like if I want to update one part of an array, I still need to send the rest of the array in it entirety. But this brings me back to the original problem of using `PUT` - I could overwrite any changes made to the other array elements in the time since I grabbed the resource.

Is there a solution here?

Answer (score 0):

> And now it could error. Because in the time since I pulled the resource and I'm pushing it back, any number of changes could've been made to the array a

Yes.  But you can check for that, with [test](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.6)

> The "test" operation tests that a value at the target location is equal to a specified value.

More generally, you can also look into using the more general [conditional requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) mechanism to communicate to the origin server which version of the resource you expect the patch to be applied to, for example by including an [eTag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3).